# Using alias column name with CASE in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I fix this query? I received below error:

> Unknown column 'count_of_confirmed_rec' in 'where clause'

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(a.col_1)FROM table_1 a
JOIN table 2 b ON a.col_id= b.col_id) count_of_confirmed_rec,
c.col_1,
FROM table_3 c
LEFT JOIN table_4 d ON c.col_id = d.col_id 
WHERE d.col_1 = 'value'
AND c.col_1 = CASE count_of_confirmed_rec
WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: You can't use alias in SELECT fields section in WHERE clause

Comment: The better approach here would be to dump all the data without your `case` condition into a temp table and fetch the records in simple `select` with `case` condition.

Comment: apart from using temp table, there's no other way to fix the query right?

Answer (score 1):

First, your subquery for computing `count_of_confirmed_rec` is not correlated with the outer query; therefore it will give you the same value for all returned rows of the query.  Not sure if this is what you want or not.

Second, your condition `d.col_1 = 'value'` also looks possibly misplaced for a Left Join.

For testing the value of `count_of_confirmed_rec` in your where statement, you need to put everything except the WHERE statement in a subquery and apply the condition on the rows returned by the query (untested):

```
select count_of_confirmed_rec, c_col_1 from (
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(a.col_1)FROM table_1 a JOIN table 2 b ON a.col_id= b.col_id) count_of_confirmed_rec, c.col_1 as c_col_1
FROM table_3 c LEFT JOIN table_4 d ON c.col_id = d.col_id 
WHERE d.col_1 = 'value'
) SQ
where c_col_1 = CASE count_of_confirmed_rec WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```